# How to downgrade version in Next.Js

Tags: reactjs, next.js, next.js13

How to downgrade Next.js version 13 to 11.
It is not working `npx create-next@11.0.0-app app-name`

I want to learn Nextjs from yt and most of the playlist uses version 12 or 11 of Nextjs.
And right now I'm using version 13 of Nextjs.So I'm always getting error and so many things.

Comment: I suggest you check YouTube for how things are done and then try checking the documentation for the latest way of doing that thing. Youtube is just there to explain how it works, don't copy paste from YouTube. Almost every video will have lots of outdated stuff. The logic almost remains the same just a few things/syntax get updated over the years with version changes

Answer (score 1):

The issue is the way you are configuring the `npx`

The correct format is `npx create-next-app@{version | "latest"}`

So you want `npx create-next-app@11 appName`

Answer (score 0):

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QcEY72FX9go&t=607s

I used `create next app -e with tailwindcss` but I only got readme and gitingnore files.

I solved this problem by using `npx create-next-app@12 news-app-yt` and after `cd news-app-yt`, `npm install -D tailwindcss postcss autoprefixer` and then `npx tailwindcss init -p`. Finally `code .`.